# How to free a struct array in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I have a **struct array** like this

```
typedef struct {
    char *name[50];
    int score;
} score;
```

Memory is allocated to that array like this

```
score *scores = (score *) malloc(sizeof(score) * size);
```

I need to do an if-check and regarding to that check I am **deallocating** that memory space. So right now, I have 2 questions in my mind

1. Why can't I just free-up space like this ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scores[i].score == scoreToBeDeleted) {
            free(scores[i].name);
            free(&(scores[i].score));
            free(&(scores[i]));
        }
    }
```

2. Should I **shift** the elements of the array as I remove records ?

Comment: It's very simple: every malloc call must be matched with a free call. If you have more free calls than malloc calls, your code is broken.

Comment: hmm.. did you really mean to do "char *name[50]" or did you want to do "char name[50]"
I have not written c in a while but char *name[50]; just looks wrong to me.

Comment: Yes you need to shift the elements and decrease `size`. As for the `free`s you only free pointers that have been allocated via `malloc` and friends, therefore `free(&(scores[i]))` and `free(&(scores[i].score))`  are wrong. `free(scores[i].name)` might be correct or not depending on how `scores[i].name` has been allocated. But as already mentioned you probably want `char name[50];` instead of `char name[50];`.

Comment: You allocated your memory as a single block with the size of the score structure.. you should NOT need to de-alocate it individually. 

just like if you malloc an array of ints you free the pointer to the resulting array not each int in the array. 

The only reason to iterate is if you turly meant the name to be dynamically allocated then you would need to 1. malloc those pointers individually, and 2) free them individually.

Comment: The [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) basically tells you exactly what is wrong: *The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, **which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`**.*

Comment: @Jabberwocky shouldn't i need to call `free(&(scores[i]))` as I only allocated memory for structs in the array. I haven't allocated memory for the name string yet.

Comment: @blackwings15 as mentioned in previous comments you only can call `free(foo)` if `foo` is a pointer that has been returne by `malloc` and friends. Ad as mentioned before: you probably want `char name[50];` or `char *name;`. Show more code and we can advide.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the only pointer that returned from `malloc()` is `scores`. However, I am unable to call `free()` on elements of `scores` array like `free(scores[i]])`

Comment: @blackwings15 why do you want to free `scores[i]`? If hasn't been allocated via `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deallocate your struct variables because you haven't allocated them explicitly, you have allocated the array of struct scores.

```
/* Allocate scores */
scores *scores[size];
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    /* Allocate scores individually */
    scores[i] = (score *) malloc(sizeof score);
}

/* Deallocate scores */
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scores[i]->score == scoreToBeDeleted) {
            free(scores[i];
        }
    }
```

This way you can achieve your desired behavior. Or you could use linked list of scores.

Comment: As `score` variable is not a pointer, I am getting an error because of using `->` instead of `.`. Other than that, as I try to call `free(scores[i])`, I get the error message :

"Passing 'score' to parameter of incompatible type 'void *'

Comment: `score *scores[size]` is an array of pointers pointing to struct score. So `score[i]` is a pointer in this case.